# How get ajax response data to a variable when binding data to kendo dropdown?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json, kendo-ui

I m using kendo drop down box to my web page. This is my java script function.

```
        function BindNonEventDownList(_propertyId, _url, _textField, _valueField) {
            $(_propertyId).kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel: '<%= Resources.ResourceiChain.Select %>',
                 dataTextField: _textField,
                 dataValueField: _valueField,
                 dataSource: {
                     type: "json",
                     serverFiltering: true,
                     transport: {
                         read: _url
                     },
                     schema: {
                         data: "Data",
                         total: "Count"

                     }
                 }
             });

        }
```

This is my Response.

```
        {"Data":[],"Count":0}
```

I want to get this count to a variable. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer......First intialized the datasource. Then using data.length you can get the length of the data..

```
     function BindNonEventDownList(_propertyId, _url, _textField, _valueField) {

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
               transport: {
                         read: _url
                     },
                     schema: {
                         data: "Data",
                         total: "Count"

                     }
            });

            dataSource.fetch(function(){
              var data = this.data();
              console.log("data:"+data.length);
            });


            $(_propertyId).kendoDropDownList({
                optionLabel: '<%= Resources.ResourceiChain.Select %>',
                 dataTextField: _textField,
                 dataValueField: _valueField,
                 dataSource: dataSource
             });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [total](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-total) method of the data source:

```
var dropdown = $(_propertyId).data("kendoDropDownList");
var count = dropdown.dataSource.total();
```

However make sure the data has been received when you call the `total` method. Otherwise it will return `0`.

Comment: I want get count inside of this function BindNonEventDownList(_propertyId, _url, _textField, _valueField) {}

Comment: You can't. You need the server response to be received.